# I want to turn off redirect to external site on my HTML5 video player embedded video

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

I have troubleshot my client code to this one line  which seems to redirect me to external site (original URL of embedded video) upon click and I want to disable it.

I went through documentation and it looks like mhp1138 has something to do with HTML5 player, but I can't find anything on it. Also how can I find the associated html file to remove the div or make the style="display: none;"? I would have also tried to update style.css file but this uses inline style which takes precedence. Don't know how to fix at this point, any suggestions?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnAJe.jpg)

Comment: You should provide a complete and minimal example of code, not an image.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment since I don't have 50 points yet, so I'll write an answer.

Have you tried to use `!important` on the CSS stylesheet to override the inline style? I know this is not ideal, but might be a workaround and might help you get started somewhere, at least that way you can test if you problem could be solved through style changes.